# Getting error in DaggerApplicationComponent in MVP

Tags: android, android-mvp

I am trying to learn about MVP pattern and following one tutorial where I got this source code.

**ApplicationModule class**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Application application;
    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideContext() {     return application;    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent interface**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent
{    void inject (MainActivity target); }
```

**App class**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private ApplicationComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //the below line is showing error
        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
    }


    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Inject
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((App) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

**module level build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.renegens.daggerexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

**build.gradle for project level**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But its showing error in DaggerApplicationComponent in app class. I had to change some settings for importing the project-  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'` to  `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` also changed `minSDK` ,`buildTool`, `compileSDK` versions and reagrding changes.

Why is it showing the error and how do I fix it? Please help me out or I am stuck.

**update**

I am getting the error message`Failed to resolve: com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12.` in Build tab in toolbar. Below is a screen shot of the message.

[image]

Comment: there is some error in when your class DaggerApplicationComponent is building,you need to check all of your module and component class ,you are missing something l.

Comment: post some logs which will clarify more about error.

Comment: @Ajay Chauhan - I have updated my question and given the error message from build.

Comment: Are you using gradle in offline mode?

Comment: @mallaudin -  gradle isnt in offline mode as its unchecked in the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the latest dagger dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
```

Apart from this add one more line to ApplicationModule interface ie

```
Context provideContext();
```

Comment: Dagger v2.12 is also there on maven. Updating is not a solution.

Comment: yeah it is there ,but we are supposed to use latest one,that's the point of updating

Comment: @Ajay - changing the dependencies made the error solved from build but its still showing red mark error in DaggerApplicationComponent. And where do you want me to put the Context provideContext()? in ApplicationComponent interface ? I tried that that doesnt work as well -its showing that method never been used.

Comment: @Ajay - well no errors anymore after clean and rebuild. I didn't really have to add Context provideContext(); Just updated the dependencies. Thanks ajay , you saved me :-)